# Marklogic: Search, score computation report

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am trying to figure out what certain documents are ranked as results for certain keyword searches.

I am using Marklogic's /MarkLogic/appservices/search and have set the relevance trace and return plan as true.

I get results like this:

```
<qry:or>
      <qry:score formula="scoreSum" computation="507+507+507+507+507+507+507+8151+507+2358+2358+9096">26019</qry:score>
      <qry:term weight="4.875">
        <qry:score formula="8*weight*logtf" computation="39*13">507</qry:score>
        <qry:key>18088380461678133729</qry:key>
        <qry:annotation>word("Marketing")</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term>
.
.
.
<qry:term weight="142.125">
        <qry:score formula="8*weight*logtf" computation="1137*8">9096</qry:score>
        <qry:key>17170145643344834189</qry:key>
        <qry:annotation>element(http://<removed this>/resolved:description,word("Marketing"))</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term>
```

What I am trying to figure out is how is the qry:term **weight**="142.125" being calculated? I know I can weight the quality of a document, of a term, and there is a quality score on the document. How does this get calculated?

I don't see anything in the documentation on the weight attribute specifically, more just on the score calculation.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/relevance

Thanks!

I found the query and below is what I believe is the relevant part of the query:

```
cts:and-query((cts:registered-query(13876289435580202480, ("unfiltered"), 1), 
        cts:or-query((cts:element-word-query(fn:QName("http://<removed>/resolved","<removed>AuthorLastName"), "Mcconnell", ("case-insensitive","diacritic-insensitive","punctuation-insensitive","lang=en"), 16), 
            cts:near-query(cts:and-query(cts:word-query("Mcconnell", ("case-insensitive","diacritic-insensitive","punctuation-insensitive","lang=en"), 1), ()), 2, ("ordered"), 1), 
            cts:element-word-query(fn:QName("http://<removed>/resolved","keyword"), "Mcconnell", ("case-insensitive","diacritic-insensitive","punctuation-insensitive","lang=en"), 14), 
            cts:near-query(cts:and-query(cts:word-query("Mcconnell", ("case-insensitive","diacritic-insensitive","punctuation-insensitive","lang=en"), 1), ()), 2, ("ordered"), 1),
```

This is the part of the score summary which connects to the element-word-query.

```
<qry:term weight="184.625">
<qry:score formula="8*weight*logtf" computation="1477*3">4431
</qry:score>
<qry:key>6578622261224561690
</qry:key>
<qry:annotation>element(http://<removed>/resolved:AuthorLastName,word("Mcconnell"))
</qry:annotation>
</qry:term>
```

I see the 16 is the weight our code injects into the element-word-query. What I still don't get it the 184.625 value. I know I can manipulate this 184.625 by increasing the 16, but how's that being calculated?

Comment: post your query here, it could be helpful

Comment: The "weight" on the query is a scaling of the weight*logtf (dividing by 8).  So 142.125 = 1137 / 8